# Minimum Distance between lat long across multiple data frames

Tags: r

I have a data frame named A which has lat and long in separate columns. Sample Data

```
ID   Lat          Long    
a          10.773046   76.6392061   
b          10.7751978  76.6368363 
c          12.954027   78.988818 
d          12.9608638  77.521573
```

I have a data frame named Test which has lat long in separate columns. Sample Data

```
Store   Lat          Long    
a          21.244769   81.63861
b          9.919337    78.14844
c          10.053961   76.32757
d          13.829922   77.49369
e          23.849729   77.93647
```

I want to run a loop over each ID to find the minimum distance from the nearest store from his lat long and store's lat long.  So ID a will check for a,b,c,d and e and find the nearest store.

Objective- Find the minimum distance and the store name.

Output should show me

```
Id          Lat          Long       Store   Distance 
a          10.773046   76.6392061   b         50ms


a$Distance <- NA  # Make an "empty" variable in my data.frame

myFunction <- function(x, y){
  distm(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), fun = distHaversine)
}


for(ii in a){
  for(jj in Test){
    tempX <- a[a$Lat == ii & Store$Lat== jj, c("Lat")]
    tempY <- a[a$Long == ii & Store$Long == jj, c("Long")]
    # "Save" results into appropriate location in my data.frame
    myFunction(tempX,tempY)
  }
}
```

I am not able to get the exact output.

Comment: You can use `outer()` or `expand.grid()` to create a matrix that calculate the distance of all combinations, then pick out the minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the geosphere library, which calculates the distance in meters (the script does convert to km).
If you dataset is a reasonable size  (ie < 50,000) performance is acceptable.

```
a <- data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),    Lat = c(10.773046, 10.7751978, 12.954027, 12.9608638), 
                Long = c(76.6392061, 76.6392061, 78.988818, 77.521573))    


b <- data.frame(Store = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), Lat = c(21.244769,  9.919337, 10.053961, 13.829922, 23.849729), 
                Long = c(81.63861, 78.14844, 76.32757, 77.49369, 77.93647))

library(geosphere)

#calculate the distance matrix
distmatrix<-distm(a[, c(3, 2)], b[,c(3, 2)])
#find closest column and get distance
closest<-apply(distmatrix, 1, which.min)
a$store<-as.character(b$Store[closest])
a$distance<-apply(distmatrix, 1, min)/1000
a

  ID      Lat     Long store  distance
1  a 10.77305 76.63921     c  86.54914
2  b 10.77520 76.63921     c  86.76789
3  c 12.95403 78.98882     d 188.71751
4  d 12.96086 77.52157     d  96.19473
```

Solution is based on a similar question: [Is there an efficient way to group nearby locations based on longitude and latitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737822/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-group-nearby-locations-based-on-longitude-and-latit/58738552#58738552)

Comment: I have 'a' data frame of 100 rows and 'b' data frame of 60000 rows.                
 This code throws an error                                                                         
 a$store<-as.character(b$Store[closest])
How to solve that

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, store, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 98

Comment: Error Solved Thanks. What is the unit of distance (km or m)

Comment: The output from the `distm` function is in meters, but `a$distance` is in km.

Answer (score 1):

you can check this out

```
    a <- data.frame(ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),    Lat = c(10.773046, 10.7751978, 12.954027, 12.9608638), 
                Long = c(76.6392061, 76.6392061, 78.988818, 77.521573))    


b <- data.frame(Store = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), Lat = c(21.244769,  9.919337, 10.053961, 13.829922, 23.849729), 
                Long = c(81.63861, 78.14844, 76.32757, 77.49369, 77.93647))

library(tidyverse)

earth.dist <- function (long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
{
  rad <- pi/180
  a1 <- lat1 * rad
  a2 <- long1 * rad
  b1 <- lat2 * rad
  b2 <- long2 * rad
  dlon <- b2 - a2
  dlat <- b1 - a1
  a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
  c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
  R <- 6378.145
  d <- R * c
  return(d)
}


a1 <- a %>%
  group_by(ID, Lat, Long) %>%
  summarise(closest = which.min(abs(Lat - b$Lat) + abs(Long - b$Long))) %>%
  mutate(Store  = b$Store[closest],
         Distance = sqrt((Lat - b$Lat[closest])^2 + (Long - b$Long[closest])^2), 
         distKm = earth.dist(Lat, Long, b$Lat[closest],b$Long[closest]))
```

Which results in:

```
a1
  ID      Lat  Long closest Store Distance distKm
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>   <int> <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a      10.8  76.6       3 c        0.784   39.4
2 b      10.8  76.6       3 c        0.786   39.4
3 c      13.0  79.0       4 d        1.73   168. 
4 d      13.0  77.5       4 d        0.870   21.2
```

Comment: Thanks . Can you help me to understand that what is the metric of distance (km or m). Additionally I read haversine is the best method to calculate distance. Also how would i get all the columns in a and just add closest store and distance in the existing data frame a. Also what is the output column closest means.

Comment: kindly let me know

Comment: it is Euclidean distance so you can change it to sth else

Comment: How can I get all the columns of data frame a against the ouput a1

Comment: I do not understand in a1 you have the "a" data extended with Store value and Distance. Just Lat and Long values are rounded

Comment: ID column is missing from "a" data frame.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. You have to add additional grouping factor

Comment: Super cool thanks... Dude any other way to convert euclidean distance to kms. Searched but did not get a decisive answer or any function.